# Flex 4 incompatibility compiler ~~error~~ warning when building in flex 3 compatibility mode

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

I'm having this weird issue when I'm trying to build the red5recorder project (with some small modifications). When i run the build normally I get a bunch of mxml errors and other library missing objects and all that.

But the problem I'm baffled by is that when i run the `mxmlc compiler` with the `--compatibility-version` option. The build command goes like this:

```
$ mxmlc --compatibility-version=3 -- file.mxml
```

When I run this I get errors about compatibility of the `Application.application` object. It throw this error:

```
Warning: 'application' has been deprecated since 4.0.  Please use 'FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication'.
```

What I don't understand is why is it giving me a compatibility error with 4.0 when I'm telling it to build for 3.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. Does the compilation succeed?

Comment: Yes it does. Actually "Error" may have not been the best word, I grant that. But still it's giving me this warning for a version I'm not building with. With the 4.0 doesn't build but the code is not supposed to build on the 4.0 so there is no problem there.

I just wanted to know if this is normal or it's indicative that there is something wrong with how I'm building the project and all that. I'm kind of a newb on Flex.

Comment: So, there is no problem there is what you're saying?

Comment: Sorry, I'm located in Germany hence the late reply. No - this shouldn't be an issue. But I'd recommend sticking to the Flex 3.x SDK if you're not migrating your code to Flex 4.x. If you are migrating to 4.x, eliminate the warnings by using the 4.x API as suggested.